# Each element of the matrix the result of operation of similar dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 2 \\
5 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$   does not necessarily be of the result by the operation of two dimensions. For instance, each element can be the result of the operation of 3 dimensions (x, y, and z).

ax + by + cz = 4;
px + qy + rz = 2;
mx + ny + oz = 5;
gx + hy + iz = 4.

So each element in a matrix is a scalar quantity that shows its length. Suppose $
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 2 \\
5 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
is the result of operation of vectors in two dimensions.

[image]

Now, suppose there is another matrix:  $
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
2 & 9 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Each element of the above matrix can again be a result of any number of dimensions. Support, this matrix be the result of 5 dimensions. Now when we multiply the two matrices, it does matter that each element of the first matrix result of operation of 2 dimensions and second matrix 5 dimensions. I mean it cannot be that first element of first matrix result of operation of 2 dimensions and second element of first matrix other than 2.

With a vector, we can know its dimension based on its number of rows. One cannot infer any idea of dimension with a matrix except that each element of the matrix result of the operation of a same number of dimensions.

Is my above understanding correct?

Also, it appears that in case of non-square matrices, two matrices can be multiplied only when the number of columns in the first matrix equal to number of rows in the second matrix. An easy explanation appreciated why so. Since each element in the matrix just a scalar quantity, how do this relate to real world data? I believe, matrix multiplication should have practical application, and it will help to see in action, how two non square matrices are multiplied to get the final matrix. That will help make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices and matrix multiplication have may interpretations which is why they're so useful. Lets look at three specific interpretations of matrices before we consider matrix multiplication and their applications.

Firstly, matrices arose when studying systems of linear equations. This was mostly motivated by gaussian elimination as matrices avoided writing down the variable names repeatedly. This is how most students are introduced to matrices.

Secondly, matrices can simply be vectors. While it's conventional to use column vectors it doesn't matter how we organize the numbers as long as we do scalar multiplication and vector addition component-wise. So for example a $2 \times 2$ matrix can be a vector with four components. If I take a $4 \times 1$ column vector it also has four components so in a natural way the are the same (isomorphic) vector spaces. In general an $n \times m$ matrix will have $nm$ components.

Finally, matrices can represent linear transformations and this is where matrix multiplication enters the picture. A linear transformation from $V$ to $U$ is a function $\varphi:V \rightarrow U$ such that for all scalars $a,b$ and all vectors $v_1,v_2 \in V$ that $\varphi(av_1+bv_2)=a\varphi(v_1)+b\varphi(v_2)$. If we choose a basis for $V$ and $U$ we can find a matrix $T$ with respect to that basis such that $\varphi(v)=Tv$ where $v$ is a column vector. We use column vectors because it lets us write this is a $Tv$ instead of $vT$. Multiplication between two matrices will act as function composition does for these transformations. Lets look at some simple examples to build intuition.

Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the canonical basis vectors. Now define $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\varphi((x,y,z))=(x,y)$. This is linear transformation from a three dimensional space to a two dimensional space and it has a matrix multiplication associated with it.The transformation now be expressed as $$Tv=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$$ and notice that we have a $2 \times 3$ matrix multiplied by a $3 \times 1$ matrix to get a $2 \times 1$ matrix. This is true in general so that if we're given a matrix that is $A$ that is $n \times m$ and another matrix $B$ that is $m \times p$ then $AB$ will be $n \times p$. This means that $BA$ can be undefined unless $p=n$. This is one of the reasons square matrices are so special.

Now we consider another transformation, this time we define $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $\phi((x,y))=(x)$. I leave the brackets on to emphasize that it is a vector with one component and not merely a real number. The matrix multiplication that expresses this transformation would be $$Sv = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x\end{bmatrix}$$.

From here we ask, what is $\phi(\varphi(v))$? This is a function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(\varphi((x,y,z)))=(x)$. Since it is the composition of two linear functions it is itself linear. We can write this system as $$Mv = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\end{bmatrix}$$.

Finally we can see that $ST = M$ (note the order) We can check that this is a $1 \times 2$ matrix multiplied by a $2 \times 3$ matrix which gives us a $1 \times 3$ matrix which makes sense since the composition is from a three dimensional space to a one dimensional space.

As for applications matrix multiplication can have a geometric interpretation with certain special matrices associated with certain geometric operations like rotations, reflections, and projections. I have personally worked with the transform object in the OpenGL graphic standard, which is represented by a $4 \times 4$ matrix. Matrix multiplication used to compute the composition of those transformations as above. It also has a variety of application in machine learning, graph theory, probability theory, representation theory, and quantum mechanics among others. It is a rich and thriving field both theoretically and in application.

To further your understanding I suggest you consider the following transformations. Take $\varphi((x))=(x,0)$ and $\phi((x,y))=(x,0,x)$. These transformations are mapped into a higher dimensional space at each step instead of lower ones. Try to find the associated rectangular matrices for each transformation, and their composition. Then see how this relates to the matrix multiplication involved.